# SmallPhotoUrl in User object is suddenly missing?

Tags: force.com

This morning, our User objects were missing the smallPhotoUrl field. I don't think we've done anything, but it's a standard field and I'm not sure how we removed it.

Any ideas what might have happened?

Comment: SF docs still show its available, If there was any update on deprecating the docs would be updated: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm. can you post what error you are getting when you try to use smallphotourl?

Comment: Check the [Setup Audit Trail](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorsetup.htm) to see if anything has changed recently that might have hidden the field.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling Chatter entirely will remove access to this field. Check Setup > Customize > Chatter > Settings.