# i have create managed packaged and got Organization-level Feature Dependencies on chatter

Tags: apex, managed-package, chatter, field-dependencies

i have create managed packaged but my controller  got Organization-level Feature Dependencies on chatter. in my controller, i'm querying the user , userRole and profile object. 
i noticed that  i'm using SmallPhotoUrl on viusfalforce page may be that's why i got  Feature Dependencies . i want to remove  chatter Feature Dependencies from my packaged . it is possible ? 
one more thing im not using chatter or feed fields or object in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reference to User.SmallPhotoUrl is causing the dependency, based on the answer to this related question:

[SmallPhotoUrl in User object is suddenly missing?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/smallphotourl-in-user-object-is-suddenly-missing)

The documentation for SmallPhotoUrl in the User SObject confirms this:
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

"SmallPhotoUrl - The URL for a thumbnail of the user's profile photo if Chatter is enabled."

Comment: Yes im user user.smallPhotoUrl , thanks for api documentation le me check if any other way to get userphoto